# Matlab: Comparing two vectors with different length and different values?

Tags: matlab

Lets say I have two vectors A and B with different lengths `Length(A) is not equal to Length(B)` and the Values in Vector A, are not the same as in Vector B. I want to compare each value of B with Values of A (Compare means if Value B(i) is almost the same value of `A(1:end)` for example `B(i)-Tolerance<A(i)<B(i)+Tolerance`.

How Can I do this without using `for loop` since the data is huge?

I know `ismember(F)`, intersect,repmat,find but non of those function can really help me

Comment: So you're only comparing `A(i)` with `B(i)`? Why not post the existing for loop code and people might be able to suggest improvement from there.

Comment: Here is a solution for ismember with a tolerance. It is about twice as slow as the solution posted by @ondav but does handle the tolerance more accurately. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23294-ismemberf/content/ismemberf.m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you are trying to do is have an `ismember` function for use on real valued data.

That is, check for each value `B(i)` in your vector `B` whether `B(i)` is within the tolerance threshold `T` of at least one value in your vector `A`

This works out something like the following:

```
tf = false(1, length(b)); %//the result vector, true if that element of b is in a
t = 0.01; %// the tolerance threshold
for i = 1:length(b)
    %// is the absolute difference between the 
    %//element of a and b less that the threshold?
    matches = abs(a - b(i)) < t; 

    %// if b(i) matches any of the elements of a
    tf(i) = any(matches);
end
```

Or, in short:

```
t = 0.01;
tf = arrayfun(@(bi) any(abs(a - bi) < t), b);
```

Regarding avoiding the for loop: while this might benefit from vectorization, you may also want to consider looking at parallelisation if your data is *that* huge. In that case having a for loop as in my first example can be handy since you can easily do a basic version of parallel processing by changing the `for` to `parfor`.

Comment: I like this, it is very nice and straightforward and solves the task. The only problem is the linear search in `any` - see my solution with execution time comparison.

Answer (score 3):

You may try a solution along these lines:

```
tol = 0.1; 

N = 1000000; 

a = randn(1, N)*1000; % create a randomly

b = a + tol*rand(1, N); % b is "tol" away from a

a_bin = floor(a/tol); 
b_bin = floor(b/tol); 

result = ismember(b_bin, a_bin) | ...
         ismember(b_bin, a_bin-1) | ...
         ismember(b_bin, a_bin+1); 

find(result==0) % should be empty matrix.
```

The idea is to discretize the a and b variables to bins of size `tol`. Then, you ask whether b is found in the same bin as any element from a, or in the bin to the left of it, or in the bin to the right of it.

**Advantages**: I believe `ismember` is clever inside, first sorting the elements of `a` and then performing sublinear (log(N)) search per element b. This is unlike approaches which explicitly construct differences of each element in b with elements from a, meaning the complexity is linear in the number of elements in a.

**Comparison**: for `N=100000` this runs 0.04s on my  machine, compared to 20s using linear search (timed using Alan's nice and concise `tf = arrayfun(@(bi) any(abs(a - bi) < tol), b);` solution).

**Disadvantages**: this leads to that the actual tolerance is anything between tol and 1.5*tol. Depends on your task whether you can live with that (if the only concern is floating point comparison, you can).

Note: whether this is a viable approach depends on the ranges of a and b, and value of tol. If a and b can be very big and tol is very small, the `a_bin` and `b_bin` will not be able to resolve individual bins (then you would have to work with integral types, again checking carefully that their ranges suffice). The solution with loops is a safer one, but if you really need speed, you can invest into optimizing the presented idea. Another option, of course, would be to write a mex extension.

Comment: Not sure what it will do to performance, but have you considered combining a_bin +-1 so you only need a single ismember?

Comment: Yes you could, and I believe that it would speed up even more because there would be just 1 internal sort. Good tip!

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Tried it - yes, this cuts down the time a bit from 0.05s to 0.04s.

Comment: @ondav This is a nice quick approach. Regarding your binning approach, have you considered just multiplying the numbers so that the part you are interested in is an integer? That is: `a_bin = round(a .* 10);` to give accuracy to 1 decimal place, and thus a tolerance of 0.1.

Comment: @Alan Yes, it actually happens here: `a_bin = floor(a/tol);`

Comment: @ondav yes, I saw that. I meant that using round and only the one ismember check automatically sets the tolerance window. Also multiplication tends to be less expensive than division.

Comment: @ondav Thancks for the help That is what i am looking for but still you created two Matrixes (a,b) with the same length as i stated before the two matrixes dose not have the same length of data

Comment: @user2573266 ondav's solution will work for matrices which do not have the same length of data; he just happened to use ones that do in his example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fully vectorized solution. Note that I would actually recommend the solution given by @Alan, as mine is not likely to work for big datasets.

```
[X Y]=meshgrid(A,B)
M=abs(X-Y)<tolerance
```

Now the logical index of elements in a that are within the tolerance can be obtained with `any(M)` and the index for B is found by `any(M,2)`

Answer (score 1):

[`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to the rescue

```
 >> M = abs( bsxfun(@minus, A, B' ) ); %//' difference
 >> M < tolerance
```

Comment: Nice, but it explicitly stores the element pair differences - memory complexity `M*N`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do what you want is with a logical expression.
Since A and B are vectors of different sizes you can't simply subtract and look for values that are smaller than the tolerance, but you can do the following:

```
Lmat = sparse((abs(repmat(A,[numel(B) 1])-repmat(B',[1 numel(A)])))<tolerance);
```

and you will get a sparse logical matrix with as many ones in it as equal elements (within tolerance). You could then count how many of those elements you have by writing:

```
Nequal = sum(sum(Lmat));
```

You could also get the indexes of the corresponding elements by writing:

```
[r,c] = find(Lmat);
```

then the following code will be true (for all j in `numel(r)`):

```
B(r(j))==A(c(j))
```

Finally, you should note that this way you get multiple counts in case there are duplicate entries in A or in B. It may be advisable to use the `unique` function first. For example:

```
A_new = unique(A);
```