# compare two vectors with different size in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two vectors **a** , **b** with different size where `size(A) = n` & `size(b) = m` and (n>m), I want to get (n-m) values after comparing as elements in both vectors are closest to others

```
a = [17    28    41    56    69    84   102   105   123   138   149   160   173   184]              

b = [17    28    42    56    69    83   123   138   149   159   173   185]
```

what I need is

```
result = [102 105]
```

with matlab

anyone can help me?

Comment: Sorry, I dont get it. You want the elements that are in one but not in the other with some threeshold for equality?

Comment: Depending on what is being asked for here, this may be a possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17612144/1133144

Comment: No, I'm trying  apply 'Curvature scale space' So I have CSS image for boundary object contour with maximum curvature points,and I want to extract the coordinate of this points . To more clear you can see this paper http://pdf.aminer.org/000/312/062/a_new_approach_to_computation_of_curvature_scale_space_image.pdf

Comment: Ah, This sounds like [Dynamic Time Warping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping), followed by identification of points with poorest fit. It also reminds me of [localised contour sequences](http://www.ijarcsse.com/docs/papers/Volume_3/7_July2013/V3I7-0380.pdf), which may be of some minor interest.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance this seems like you could get away with using [setdiff](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/ref/setdiff.html) if you are only dealing with integer values, however this is actually a bit more complicated.

If I have understood the scenario correctly you are looking to find the `D` (where `D = n-m`) values in array `a` which are the least similar to any element in array `b`.

The solution given by Luis Mendo will achieve this, however it involved a memory complexity of MxN, which can be prohibitive for larger arrays.

An alternative approach would be the following:

```
[~, mi] = sort(arrayfun(@(ai) min(abs(b - ai)), a), 'descend');
c = a(mi(1:length(a) - length(b)));
```

Or, in a more expanded format:

```
aDiff = nan(1,length(a));
for ai = 1:length(a) %//for each element in A, find...
    aDiff(ai) = min(abs(b - a(ai))); %//the difference from it's closest match in b
end

[~, mi] = sort(aDiff, 'descend'); %//find the elements with the largest difference
d = length(a) - length(b); %//determine how many to return
c = a(mi(1:d)); %//take the D elements with the biggest difference from A
```

The benefit of these approaches is that it keeps the memory requirements down to `2*length(a)` or there abouts, and it can be parallelized over multiple cores if necessary.

Comment: I try to get a result using setdiff and intersect but didn't work, thank you for your help

Comment: Ah, of course, you have a small matching threshold which would have to be accounted for.

Comment: Yes, it work too, I'm sorry I didn't know all this commands (arrayfun , bsxfun,...)in matlab because I'm a new user . thanks a lot Alan

Comment: @user3496585 yeah, they can seem pretty esoteric to new users. They are basicly short hand for `for` loops. For example: `bob = arrayfun(@(x) x - 2, a)` would translate as: "Subtract 2 from each element in the array `a` and put the results in the array `bob`". `bsxfun` is similar, but you get to provide two arrays and must give a binary function (one that takes two inputs).

Answer (score 1):

```
dist = abs(bsxfun(@minus, a(:).', b(:))); %'// distance for all combinations
[~, ind] = sort(min(dist),'descend'); %// compute minimum distance for each
%// element of a, and sort
result = a(ind(1:(numel(a)-numel(b)))); %// pick n-m elements of a with largest
%// minimum distance
```

Comment: Goooooooooooooooooooood, Thank you very much Luis Mendo, Now it work with me