# Find nearest smaller value in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have two vectors of different size. Just as an example:

```matlab
Triggs = [38.1680, 38.1720, 38.1760, 38.1800, 38.1840, 38.1880, 38.1920, 38.1960, 38.2000, 38.2040, 38.2080, 38.2120, 38.2160, 38.2200, 38.2240, 38.2280, 38.2320, 38.2360, 38.2400, 38.2440, 38.2480, 38.2520, 38.2560, 38.2600, 38.2640, 38.2680]

Peaks =  [27.7920, 28.4600, 29.1360, 29.8280, 30.5200, 31.2000, 31.8920, 32.5640, 33.2600, 33.9480, 34.6520, 35.3680, 36.0840, 36.7680, 37.5000, 38.2440, 38.9920, 39.7120, 40.4160, 41.1480, 41.8840, 42.5960, 43.3040, 44.0240, 44.7160, 45.3840, 46.1240, 46.8720, 47.6240, 48.3720, 49.1040, 49.8080, 50.5200, 51.2600]
```

For each element in `Triggs` I need to find the nearest smaller element in `Peaks`.

That is, if `Triggs(1) == 38.1680`, I need to find the column number equal to `Peaks(15)` (the 15th element of Peaks).

Just to be 100% clear, the closest element of course could be the next one, that is `38.2440`. That would not be ok for me. I will always need the one to the left of the array.

So far I have this:

```
for i = 1:length(triggersStartTime)
    [~,valuePosition] = (min(abs(Peaks-Triggs(i))))
end
```

However, this could give me the incorrect value, that is, one bigger than `Triggs(i)`, right?

As a solution I was thinking I could do this:

```
for i = 1:length(Triggs)
    [~,valuePosition] = (min(abs(Peaks-Triggs(i))))
    if Peaks(valuePosition) >= Triggs(i)
        valuePosition = valuePosition-1
    end
end
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: What if there is no such value? What should be output then?

Comment: Sorry Luis, I hadn't noticed this comment. Because of the way my data are collected it should be impossible to have a Trigger not preceded by a peak. That is, one vector is cardiac R-Peaks, the other is triggers marking stimulus presentation. The stimulus presentation should always come after an r-peak. Therefore, if there is no peak before the trigger, it means that there is something really wrong. Also, I have noticed that I was doing something wrong in my script, therefore the values that I copied here are not correct. That's why it could be confusing. I do have the correct values now.

Comment: In that case you can omit the last line. I have edited my answer

Comment: Great, thank you again Luis, for the great solution and for your time and consideration. Amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in a vectorized way as follows (note that the intermediate matrix `d` can be large). If there is no number satisfying the condition the output is set to `NaN`.

```
d = Triggs(:).'-Peaks(:); % matrix of pair-wise differences. Uses implicit expansion
d(d<=0) = NaN; % set negative differences to NaN, so they will be disregarded
[val, result] = min(d, [], 1); % for each column, get minimum value and its row index
result(isnan(val)) = NaN; % if minimum was NaN the index is not valid
```

If it is assured that there will always be a number satisfying the condition, the last line and the variable `val` can be removed:

```
d = Triggs(:).'-Peaks(:); % matrix of pair-wise differences. Uses implicit expansion
d(d<=0) = NaN; % set negative differences to NaN, so they will be disregarded
[~, result] = min(d, [], 1); % for each column, get row index of minimum value
```

Comment: I have to say, I don't really understand this but it seems to be working like a charm ^_^ I'll try to understand how you did it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Glu I added some comments

Comment: Thank you so much, that's really helpful.

Comment: Btw, I have noticed now that I had made some mistakes with the variable names when explaining. I just amended it

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help you:

```
 temp=sort(abs(Peaks-Triggs));
 lowest=find(abs(Peaks-Triggs)==temp(1))
```

Comment: Thank you Evyatar, however if I try running the first line it says: Matrix dimensions must agree 
 ...

Comment: Oh sorry i just now realized that the two vectors are not in the same length

Comment: Maybe this will help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015617/compare-two-vectors-with-different-size-in-matlab

Comment: It seems like Luis solution worked but thank you very much for your time and contribution =)